# How can I find distinct items in a collection excluding a particular value in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, pymongo, distinct-values

I would like to select all the distinct values of the field "name" in a collection, with the condition that the field "sex" must be "male and the field "state" must not be "FR" 
(all the distinct inventors' names that are male and not french).

I have tried this code but can't find any results. Is it correct?

```
inventors = db.collection.distinct("name", {"$and": [{"sex":"male"}, {"state": {"$nin": "FR"}}]})
```

I'm using PyCharm as IDE

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "not in", use ["not equal"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/). Replace:

```
{"$nin": "FR"}
```

with:

```
{"$ne": "FR"}
```

Comment: I've just tried with both the operators. There aren't results

Comment: @DiegoFosso are you sure you connect to the correct mongodb instance and use the right collection? `db.collection.distinct` would query the `collection` collection.